# Python Regular expression to extract a substring

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

`"  request.addParameter('page','/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag','N','',true,false); "`.

I want to extract the part

`" '/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag' "`

out of this string. I tried several combinations of regex (using re module in python) but can't find the exact desired pattern that gives me the substring  out of the main string.

Comment: Can you put those combinations of regex that you tried into your question?

Comment: Does the string always begin with a `/`

Comment: pat = re.search("\'\/[a-z]*[A-Z]*[./+]",string1)
pat = re.search("\'\/(.+)\?(.\w)",string1)
pat = re.search("\'\/(.+)?(.\w*)",string1)
pat = re.search("\'\/(.+)?(.\W*)",string1)
pat = re.search("\'\/(.+)?(\w*\d*)\'",string1)
pat = re.search("\'\/(.+)?(\w*\d*)\'[^,]",string1)
pat = re.search("\'\/(\w+)?'",string1)

Comment: @Harvey **In the question** please, not in comments. You can edit your question and add that at the end.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R   It begins with a single quote followed by /

Comment: @Harvey Added an aswer. It begins with a single quote followed by /

Comment: @Harvey did you want `'` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'([^']+)'
```

You can try this.

Do `print re.findall(r"'([^']+)'",x)[1]`.

Here x is your string.Basically it is extracting the second group.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/2

Comment: I didn't. In fact you're a STAR.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex

```
'\/[^']+'
```

The code can be written as

```
x="  request.addParameter('page','/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag','N','',true,false); ".
re.findall(r"'\/[^']+'", x)"
["'/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag'"]
```

see how the regex works http://regex101.com/r/pK9mI8/1

you can also use `search` function to search and find the substring matching the  pattern as

```
 re.search(r"'\/[^']+'", x).group()
"'/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "  request.addParameter('page','/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag','N','',true,false); "
>>> re.search(r"'(/[^']*)'", s).group(1)
'/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not forced to use `regex` you can use `split()`:

```
>>> s.split(',')[1]
"'/TMRMKUOHY/RPM/Store/srrreVkew.jsp?resODFlag'"
```

Comment: yep, for extract a substring you can use some ways that regex is one of them ,  so if you find this answer useful you can tell this to community by up voting ,